# Yahama MG10XU Mixer USB Input Messes Up

Tags: mixer, usb

So basically I have a Yahama MG10XU Mixer for an 11-hour long event. Now the hall the event was taking place was very hot 90% of the time, around 80F to 88F.

Now the problem I had was basically my USB input from the mixer would do weird random things. Sometimes the pitch would go high, sometimes they audio would freeze every 5 seconds, or sometimes everything became distorted.

Not only did this ruin part of my recordings and the broadcast of the event, but I'm not sure what caused it, it might have been the temperature, but the specs say it can go up to 40C (104F).

Extra info I could add to help would be I had 2 Shure Gooseneck Mics to a Splitter which blocks 48V PH from the PA system from going to my mixer, I also had a regular run of the mill dynamic mic, and I had my Zoom H6 plugged into the line in.

Can anyone help me identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, it was just recording via USB that had the problems, not the audio output of the desk?

Comment: @SimonBosley Yup, and the live stream software that I was using also had it. Not sure, but I also think the same messed up audio came out of the headphone jack, not sure.

Comment: Closing - this was just a hardware fault, not on topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I own MG10XU as well and I experienced the same -- even though after a replacement. The audio sound becomes lengthened and laggy(about 8%). Listen to the [sound file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-c4G2cSUoZva0xGS1Y5UXhpSVE)(the first part is original, and the second part after drum sound is distorted one). The waveform is as follows:

[image: waveform]

You see two tracks of the same audio. The top is the original and the bottom is through MG10XU when it's acting strange. The bottom is about 8% longer than the top. When you hear the bottom you can notice the distorted sound.

I have researched the cause and solution. My current understanding is, it's due to the device driver.

According to the release notes for the USB driver v1.9.8 at [YAMAHA](http://download.yamaha.com/search/detail/?site=usa.yamaha.com&language=en&category_id1=16523&category_id2=16067&category_id3=16506&product_id=1904369&asset_file_language=EN&asset_id=67109), they claim they solved the following problems:

- Audio loss may occur depending on the user environment.
- Audio may distort after some period of time.

However, I still experience those symptoms with v1.9.8. One way to avoid this was choosing 44.1khz as the sample rate. Anything else causes the problem, especially when the system goes into any kind of sleep and wake up.

If you had to use a different sample rate other than 44.1khz, then use it but once you experience the problem, switch the rate to something else and then come back to the original sample rate. Then usually it's gone. If it doesn't you have to restart the mixer by the on/off switch.

Comment: I contacted Yamaha and got a replacement mixer. I use old skool stereo out to line in on my sound card for now.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same behavior on my MG10XUF (same device, only with faders) and i do not use the Yamaha drivers, just the good old USB Win drivers.

As i had the "bitcrushed" output drops, i used the device manager and uninstalled every instance of USB connected device (i am from germany, they are called "USB-Verbundgerät" here) listed in the USB-Controller section.

After that, i switched off the MG10XUF and switched back on. All the devices i had where reinstalled and the problem was gone.

I think the devices where just resettet and maybe got a new order, if this makes sense, but it helped.